# Associating two tables through a lookup-table with custom column names sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize,  what is the correct way to link `tableA` with `tableB` through `linkingTable`? I can't find a good example where all the column names are customized
(because working with an existing database)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const tableA = sequelize.define("tableA", {
        a_id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: "tableA"
    });

    return tableA
}
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const tableB = sequelize.define("tableB", {
        b_id:{type: DataTypes.STRING}
        new_data: {type: DataTypes.STRING}
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: "tableB"
    });
    return tableB
}
```

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const linkingTable = sequelize.define("linkingTable", {
        bId: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
        a_id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: "linkingTable"
    });
    return linkingTable
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `linkingTable` should have its own PK field.
Whiie defining a M:N association using `belongsToMany` you can indicate both `foreignKey` (a field of a model for which you call `belongsToMany`) and `otherKey` (a field of a model which you pass as the first argument to `belongsToMany`).

```js
tableA.belongsToMany(tableB, { through: linkingTable, foreignKey: 'a_id', otherKey: 'bId' });
tableB.belongsToMany(tableA, { through: linkingTable, foreignKey: 'bId', otherKey: 'a_id' });
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I had to make an edit. I forgot to include that the linking column name is different in the linking table. The database design doesn't have an underscore in the linking table! Can you modify your answer? I edited the linking table ```b_id -> bId```

Comment: Modified. Look at it again

Comment: Argh so strange. It worked. But the documents of belongsToMany say foreignKey is the name of foreignKey in source model. Here, source model I think is table B, so I thought foreignKey should be b_id as in table B...  https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-belongsToMany

Comment: It looks like: foreignKey is the key in through table for source table, otherKey is the foreign key in through table for target table.

Comment: By indicating `foreignKey` and `otherKey` in `belongsToMany` you just tell Sequelize which columns should be used in a junction table because Sequelize uses primary key fields from both source and target tables automatically to link them with the junction table columns.

Comment: Yes, you're right, exactly because there is no need to indicate columns from tableA and table. Sequelize always uses primary key fields on the side 1 in 1:N or N:1 associations and on both sides of M:N association because we need a field with unique values to identify each record when we link tables.